# Unable to add customAppSettingsGroup inside my console application app.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, console-application, app-config

I am working on an asp.net console application , and i am trying to add a custom app settings section to encrypt it, as follow:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <customAppSettingsGroup>
    <customAppSettings>
      <add key="KeyOne" value="****" />
    </customAppSettings>
  </customAppSettingsGroup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConcurrentRequests" value="100" />
    <add key="ApiLimit" value="100" />
    <add key="FullScanDay" value="Tuesday" />
    <add key="logsFilePath" value="C:\logslogs\" />
    <add key="TPSFilePathAndName" value="C:\ctps_ns.txt" />
    <add key="PhoneNumberLength" value="11" />
  </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

but when i run the console application i will get this error:-

```
ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section customAppSettingsGroup.
```

any advice?

EDIT-

I tried this inside my app.config:-

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="customAppSettingsGroup">
      <section name="customAppSettings"
               type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler,System" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <customAppSettingsGroup>
    <customAppSettings>
      <add key="KeyOne" value="****" />
    </customAppSettings>
  </customAppSettingsGroup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConcurrentRequests" value="100" />
    <add key="ApiLimit" value="100" />
    <add key="FullScanDay" value="Tuesday" />
    <add key="logsFilePath" value="C:\logslogs\" />
    <add key="TPSFilePathAndName" value="C:\ctps_ns.txt" />
    <add key="PhoneNumberLength" value="11" />
  </appSettings>
  <startup> 
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

but when i try to access the section using this code:-

```
NameValueCollection settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customAppSettingsGroup/customAppSettings")               as System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection;
```

i got this exception:-

> Could not load file or assembly 'System' or one of its dependencies.
> The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: You didn't define `customAppSettingsGroup`

Comment: @Arsen can you advice more on this please? where i need to define it? as usually do this inside asp.net mvc web application without any issues

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="customAppSettingsGroup">
      <section name="customAppSettings"
               type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler,System" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <customAppSettingsGroup>
    <customAppSettings>
      <add key="KeyOne" value="****" />
    </customAppSettings>
  </customAppSettingsGroup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConcurrentRequests" value="100" />
    <add key="ApiLimit" value="100" />
    <add key="FullScanDay" value="Tuesday" />
    <add key="logsFilePath" value="C:\logslogs\" />
    <add key="TPSFilePathAndName" value="C:\ctps_ns.txt" />
    <add key="PhoneNumberLength" value="11" />
  </appSettings>
  <startup> 
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but i am getting this error now `Could not load file or assembly 'System' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'` on the following line of code `NameValueCollection settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customAppSettingsGroup/customAppSettings")

             as System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection;`

Comment: @John John Do you open configuration file with the `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` function?

Comment: @John John In config file change section to this `<section name="customAppSettings"         type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />` and in the code call this before getting the section `var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);`